# My tab panel which I created with html, css & Javascript is not working

Tags: javascript, jsfiddle, tabpanel

I created a tabbed panel with Javascript. When I am doing it without any programming it is working fine but after putting some it with some conditional and looping statements it is not working. Some problem is coming while making a programme in javascript. Kindly click below to look entire coding in jsfiddle and suggest me how to fix the error. Thanks

HTML :

```
<button class="tabButton">Tab 01</button>
<button class="tabButton">Tab 02</button>
<button class="tabButton">Tab 03</button>
<button class="tabButton">Tab 04</button>
<button class="tabButton">Tab 05</button>

<div class="tabPanel" style="display:block">
    <h3>Tab panel 01</h3>
    <p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed in rebus apertissimis nimium longi sumus. Quicquid porro animo cernimus, id omne oritur a sensibus; Ergo instituto veterum, quo etiam Stoici utuntur, hinc capiamus exordium. Philosophi autem in suis lectulis plerumque moriuntur. Falli igitur possumus. 
    </p>
</div>

<div class="tabPanel">
    <h3>Tab panel 02</h3>
    <p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed in rebus apertissimis nimium longi sumus. Quicquid porro animo cernimus, id omne oritur a sensibus; Ergo instituto veterum, quo etiam Stoici utuntur, hinc capiamus exordium. Philosophi autem in suis lectulis plerumque moriuntur. Falli igitur possumus.
    </p>
</div>

<div class="tabPanel">
    <h3>Tab panel 03</h3>
    <p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed in rebus apertissimis nimium longi sumus. Quicquid porro animo cernimus, id omne oritur a sensibus; Ergo instituto veterum, quo etiam Stoici utuntur, hinc capiamus exordium. Philosophi autem in suis lectulis plerumque moriuntur. Falli igitur possumus. 
    </p>
</div>

<div class="tabPanel">
    <h3>Tab panel 04</h3>
    <p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed in rebus apertissimis nimium longi sumus. Quicquid porro animo cernimus, id omne oritur a sensibus; Ergo instituto veterum, quo etiam Stoici utuntur, hinc capiamus exordium. Philosophi autem in suis lectulis plerumque moriuntur. Falli igitur possumus.
    </p>
</div>

<div class="tabPanel">
    <h3>Tab panel 05</h3>
    <p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed in rebus apertissimis nimium longi sumus. Quicquid porro animo cernimus, id omne oritur a sensibus; Ergo instituto veterum, quo etiam Stoici utuntur, hinc capiamus exordium. Philosophi autem in suis lectulis plerumque moriuntur. Falli igitur possumus. 
    </p>
</div>
```

css:

```
.tabPanel{
     width:500px;
    height:150px;
    background-color:grey;
    margin:0;
    padding:20px;
    display:none;
}
```

Javascript:

```
for (i=0; i<tabBtn.length; i++) {
    tabBtn[i].onclick = function(){
            for(r=0; r<panel.length; r++){
                    if ( i==r ){
                    panel[r].style.display = "block";
                    }   else   {
                    panel[r].style.display = "none";
                    }
            }
    }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/suhailyazdan/vwc42r9x/17/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is happening here is that by the time the 'onclick' handler runs, the for loop has already completed.

Think of it like this: Javascript encounters the for loop, loops through 5 times, attaches the handlers then exits the for loop.

When tabBtn is clicked on, it has the final value of the for loop stored inside. `i` will ALWAYS be equal to 5. Try it yourself, `console.log(i)` within your click handler and you will see it's always 5.

How do we fix this? Well, we take advantage of something called a closure. A closure is a function that will 'save' the value of i and pass it to your click handler. There is plenty of documentation on closures, and while it is a more advanced JS topic I would recommend reading up on it.

Anyway, here is how you would use a closure to fix it:

```
for (i = 0; i < tabBtn.length; i++) {
  //Here is our 'closure' an Immediately Invoked anonymous function whose job is to pass (i)!
  (function(i) {
    tabBtn[i].onclick = function() {
      for (r = 0; r < panel.length; r++) {
        if (i == r) {
          panel[r].style.display = "block";
        } else {
          panel[r].style.display = "none";
        }
      }
    }
    //Here we pass it (i) at the run time.
  })(i);
}
```

Check an updated demo here:
https://jsfiddle.net/vwc42r9x/21/

Comment: Thanks a lot... and it is working fine. As i dont know much about closures... I have to study something about it.. If any doubt comes again I would like to ask you..

Would you like to recommend any tutorial or blog on Closure so that I can understand your coding properly...

Thanks

Comment: You can read up a little more here: https://gist.github.com/amysimmons/3d228a9a57e30ec13ab1 and watch this video. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rBBwrBRoOOY Otherwise do a Google search for Closures Javascript and understand that ES5 'var' only has function scope.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your guidance... if anything comes I would like to contact you for help... Thanks